# Show values of the db in organization with Bootstrap row class for every 3 columns

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote some code which retrieves data from the database and gives the output to the web page using php. I use bootstrap to show the data in some organized way on the web page. But the code returns some syntax errors.

```
function break_array($array, $page_size) {
    $arrays = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($array as $index => $item) {
        if ($i++ % $page_size == 0) {
            $arrays[] = array();
            $current = & $arrays[count($arrays)-1];
        }
        $current[] = $item;
    }
    return $arrays;
}
?>

<?php

foreach (break_array($row = $sql->fetch(), 3) as $columns) {
    <div class="row"> *** Error is gives on here ***
    foreach ($columns as $article) {
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>{{ strip_tags(str_limit($article->body, $limit = 90, $end = '...')) }}</p>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
}
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'code' is mixing HTML with PHP in an incorrect way. PHP needs to be interpreted server side to generate HTML, this HTML is then sent to the browser and is the source-code for the browser.

You can mix PHP & HTML in a couple of ways. Here some examples:

**1. Enter and leaver php parsing mode**

Note that all PHP-code that needs to be interpreted is between `<?php ... ?>` tags, this is interpreted at the server side.

```
<?php foreach (break_array($row = $sql->fetch(), 3) as $columns) { ?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($columns as $article) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p><?php {{ strip_tags(str_limit($article->body, $limit = 90, $end = '...')) }} ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**2. Echo HTML as strings in PHP**

Note that all HTML-code is inside a php `echo()` statement:

```
<?php
foreach (break_array($row = $sql->fetch(), 3) as $columns) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($columns as $article) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        echo '  <p>' . strip_tags(str_limit($article->body, $limit = 90, $end = '...')) . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I personally don't like this solutions...  I would prefer using <?php foreach() : ?>  .... <?php endforeach ?> Read more on http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php